# Should service layer take objects or id's as input? Should responses be objects?

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I have a fairly familiar design where I have a DAO per model, and then a Model service class that uses the DAO and has all the business logic in it.

I'm a bit confused as to how to properly create these service classes, **specifically what should my parameters be and my responses be like.**

Say I have a JSON action, I could read the JSON, and then load the objects I need and THEN pass those to the service, or I could simply pass in the ID's and then load the objects in the service method.

The confusion is, I could be doing some of these things in my controllers action, or I could be doing it in my service layer.  Is there a clear cut answer to these types of questions?

pseudo code below:

```
UserDao
  save
  update
  delete
  getById

UserService
  private userDao

  GetUser
  Update
```

I will be using my service layer in BOTH the web application and the API layer.

I could have a method like:

```
def GetSomething(userId: Int, locationId: Int, ...): Something = { ... }
```

or I could have it like:

```
def GetSomething(request: GetSomethingRequest): GetSomethingResponse { ... }
```

Is it one or the other, or should I be mixing both?

Comment: Interesting question. What do you by API layer? The routes or the controllers? And why do you differentiate it from the web application?

Comment: Are you looking for thoughts and ideas specific to scala and the play framework, or more general?

Answer (score 0):

First I think using case classes for ids is a good desing so will use `UserId(id: Int)` and `LocationId(id: Int)` 
Lets say You have a model like this: `User(id: UserId, locations: Set[Location])`

Then lets say that You want to serve request like `/user/1/location/1`
Your controller needs to handle this by returning `Location` json. In order to do this You need to
1. Find `User` by id (may not exist -> NotFound(user with id))
2. For `User` find `Location` (may not exist -> NotFound(location with id)

Taking all this into account, You'll need a service: `def find(userId: UserId):Option[User] = {...}`. Then in Your `User` add a function to find a location: def findLocation(id: LocationId): Option[Location]. Putting 
`findLocation` in `User` prevents so called 'anemic model'

For update things are a bit different. Your `Location` will probably have fields that are updated automatically (example: version, state etc.). So 
you will need another class like eg: `LocationData` (it can be mapped to form, json etc) and a method `def update(data: LocationData): Location` on  `Location` which will apply the update.